# JSON.parse fails in jQuery when PHP response-header contains "application/json"

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, http-headers

I'm getting a bit of a headache trying to figure this one out. To request some json-data from a PHP-script via Ajax, I'm using the jQuery function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: 'false',
    url: ajaxUrl,
    data: dataString,
    success: updatePage
});
```

If I *don't* set content-type in the PHP header to:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Then my response from the server looks like this:

```
{"content":"new content"}
```

And the content-type is automatically set to text/html. When dataType in the jQuery ajax options is unset, it uses a default of 'intelligent guessing'. I'm *strongly* assuming that jQuery recognizes the response-data as json because updatePage is parsed an object. updatePage uses the JSON js library(json2.js), and does this:

```
function updatePage(data) {
  $dataObj = JSON.parse(data); 
}
```

When the function is called upon ajax succes, everything works fine. No errors.
Here's the strange thing, if I set my header to application/json as above, JSON.parse suddenly reports an error. The exact same error happens if i set my dataType to 'json' in the jQuery ajax request. The response I get from the PHP script when changing these things looks exactly like the one above. The error looks like this in Firebug:

```
JSON.parse
  $dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
```

Kind of a long one, sorry, but If anyone knows what is wrong their help is greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I don't understand (or even see) the error ...

Comment: I'd suggest using console.log(data) to dump what's coming from the server... see if it looks different. That error that you've postedis not very enlightening.

Comment: Dancrumb that renders: 
 Object { content="content":"new content" }
JSON.parse
[Break on this error] $dataObj = JSON.parse(data); Not much help either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because you end up trying to double-parse the return value.

Both the explicit `json` data type and usage of the `application/json` MIME type cause jQuery to parse the returned string into a JavaScript object for you.

So, your usage of `JSON.parse()`, in these cases, is superfluous.

Comment: Oh dear god you are absolutely right, can't believe I missed that one.
Thank you

Comment: I get it, man.  Sometimes all you need is a 2nd pair of eyes.